# GDB: show arguments for function before calling it

Tags: gdb

In `gdb` is there a command that will show me the arguments for a function that I can call? I'd like to enter `info functions` to discover what functions are available, then discover what arguments one of those functions expects. (I'm looking for a solution for the most generic case, where I can't count on having the source code or an executable compiled with debug info.)

I realise that you can enter `info args` in `gdb` to view the args for the current function. My question is unrelated to that.

I also realise that you can enter `disassemble <function>` to view the assembly and thereby reverse-engineer the arguments. I hope that there's a faster, more readable alternative.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to enter `info functions` to discover what functions are available, then discover what arguments one of those functions expects.

That is *exactly* what `info functions` does, provided you have compiled code with debug info. For example:

```
// foo.c
int foo(int x, int y)
{
  return x + y;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  return foo(1, -1);
}
```

Compile with `gcc -g foo.c` and:

```
(gdb) info functions

File foo.c:
1:      int foo(int, int);
6:      int main(int, char **);
...
```

Without debug info, GDB can't tell you anything about `C` functions -- it would have to disassemble the target function and reverse-engineer the arguments, and it's not that smart.

For `C++`, it can do a little bit better: after `g++ foo.c`:

```
0x0000000000001125  foo(int, int)
0x0000000000001139  main
```

Here `main` has `extern "C"` linkage, so its arguments aren't mangled. But `foo()` has `C++` linkage, so the argument types can be deduced from the mangled name even without the debug info.

Comment: Thanks. I'm assuming that the source code is unavailable to me. So I can’t compile it with debug information

Comment: "I am assuming ..." -- don't assume, check instead. The availability of source and availability of debug info are orthogonal -- you can have either without the other. If you don't have debug info, and are dealing with `C`, then the answer is "no".

Comment: Excuse my imprecision of speech. I mean that I'm looking for a solution for the most generic case, where I can't count on having the source code. I've updated the language of my question to be more precise (but I can't update my comment because it's too old.) But thanks for the answer! +1